# karma error "SyntaxError: Expected token 'in'" at js/controllers/batch.js: 9

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

Googling has turned up a few related issues, but nothing that solved my problem. Line 9 in the js file is empty. If I exclude that file from the tests, I still get error, but at the same line in a different file. Anyone have any idea what might be causing this? This is an angularjs 1.5 project.
Thanks

Comment: Just to add, if I exclude all my js files and run Karma, I still get an error, but it does not point to any file, so something must wrong somewhere other than in my js files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out in my own project after using Safari 9 and debugging: we had a template that included a for loop with the "let" keyword used instead of "var". Since templates do not get transpiled, older browsers (depending on which one you're running in Karma) may get tripped up by the newer ES6 style.

For me, it was a line looking like this:

```
for(let i=0; i<5; i++) {
```

Comment: Indeed, the issue was mixing ES5/6 code. I was using a for loop with the ES6 style 'for' keyword. A real pain to debug this one.

Comment: Or more accurately, PhantomJS was choking on it.